# Hit Angularjs $injector: unpr error when creating custom angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I defined blew directive:

```
 define(['angular', './routes', './services', './controllers'], function(angular, userRoutes, userService, userController) {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('yourprefix.user', ['ngCookies', 'ngRoute', 'user.routes', 'user.services']);
  app.directive('pwCheck', function ($document) {
         return {
           restrict: 'A',
           require: 'ngModel',
           link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
             var firstPassword = '#' + attrs.pwCheck;
             elem.add(firstPassword).on('blur', function () {
               scope.$apply(function () {
                 var v = elem.val()===$(firstPassword).val();
                 ctrl.$setValidity('pwmatch', v);
               });
             });
           }
         };
       }).directive('oldPwdCheck', function($document, $log, userService){
         return {
           restrict: 'A',
           require: 'ngModel',
           link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
             var oldPwd = '#' + attrs.oldPwdCheck;
             elem.add(oldPwd).on('blur', function() {
               scope.$apply(function(){
                 var pass = {};
                 pass.value = elem.val();
                 userService.validatePassword(pass).then(function(result) {
                   $log.info(result);
                   ctrl.$setValidity('oldPwdMatch', result);
                 });
               });
             });
           }
         };
       });
  return app;
});
```

For the dependency userService definition:

```
define(['angular', 'common'], function (angular) {
  'use strict';

  var mod = angular.module('user.services', ['yourprefix.common', 'ngCookies']);
  mod.factory('userService', ['$http', '$q', 'playRoutes', '$cookies', '$log', function ($http, $q, playRoutes, $cookies, $log) {
    var user, token = $cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'];

    /* If the token is assigned, check that the token is still valid on the server */
    if (token) {
      $log.info('Restoring user from cookie...');
      playRoutes.controllers.Users.authUser().get()
        .success(function (data) {
          $log.info('Welcome back, ' + data.name);
          user = data;
        })
        .error(function () {
          $log.info('Token no longer valid, please log in.');
          token = undefined;
          delete $cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'];
          return $q.reject("Token invalid");
        });
    }

    return {
      loginUser: function (credentials) {
        return playRoutes.controllers.Application.login().post(credentials).then(function (response) {
          // return promise so we can chain easily
          token = response.data.token;
          return playRoutes.controllers.Users.authUser().get();
        }).then(function (response) {
          user = response.data;
          return user;
        });
      },
      logout: function () {
        // Logout on server in a real app
        delete $cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'];
        token = undefined;
        user = undefined;
        return playRoutes.controllers.Application.logout().post().then(function () {
          $log.info("Good bye ");
        });
      },
      getUser: function () {
        return user;
      },
      modifyPassword: function(newPwd) {
        return playRoutes.controllers.Users.modifyPassword(user.id).put(newPwd).then(function(response) {
          return response.data;
        });
      },
      validatePassword: function(oldPwd) {
        return playRoutes.controllers.Users.validatePassword(user.id).put(oldPwd).then(function(response) {
          return response.data;
        }).catch(function(error){
          $log.error(error);
          return false;
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
  /**
   * Add this object to a route definition to only allow resolving the route if the user is
   * logged in. This also adds the contents of the objects as a dependency of the controller.
   */
  mod.constant('userResolve', {
    user: ['$q', 'userService', function ($q, userService) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var user = userService.getUser();
      if (user) {
        deferred.resolve(user);
      } else {
        deferred.reject();
      }
      return deferred.promise;
    }]
  });
  /**
   * If the current route does not resolve, go back to the start page.
   */
  var handleRouteError = function ($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function (/*e, next, current*/) {
      $location.path('/');
    });
  };
  handleRouteError.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location'];
  mod.run(handleRouteError);
  return mod;
});
```

The code works fine on my local machine, but error raised when I deployed the code to the remote ALIYUN machine. I am learning angular and I am not able to figure out what's the problem. How can i fix it?

```
Error: 
[$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=eProvider%20%3C-%20e%20%3C-%20oldPwdCheckDirective
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do, why is the error you get not what you are expecting (what were you expecting anyway ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**From Angular Doc**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

> **Implicit Annotation**
>
> Careful: If you plan to minify your code, your service names will get
>   renamed and break your app.

You need to ensure you code is using inline array annotation of DI while injecting dependency. If you are not using it then it will cause an issue while minifying JavaScript.

```
 app.directive('pwCheck',['$document', function ($document) {
     return {
       restrict: 'A',
       require: 'ngModel',
       link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
         //code here
       }
     };
   }]).directive('oldPwdCheck', ['$document', '$log', 'userService', function($document, $log, userService){
     return {
       restrict: 'A',
       require: 'ngModel',
       link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
         //..code..herer..
       }
     };
   }]);
```

Comment: It works now after I take your suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TracyLu please do accept answer.so that other person will having same problem will know that this is solution..Thanks :)

Comment: meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers Go to this link